# [Python]: Estimating upper bound of a CDF for a given value

Tags: python, statistics, cdf

Hi I was wondering if anyone knew of a function in `numpy` or maybe `scipy` that could help with a problem I am trying to solve. Essentially what I want to do is estimate the upper bound of a CDF for a given value i.e.

[image]

where `p(x)` is the PDF. What I need to do is given some value for `y` guess the value of `x` that gives me a CDF value of `y`. I can't do it analytically because my `p(x)` does not integrate nicely. One idea I have is to just use `quad` from `numpy.integrate` to estimate the integral for many values of `x` but I think this will be very inefficient and I was wondering if there was some function that could do this for me in a more efficient manner (that is guess the `x` given some `y`).

Does such a thing exist? For reference, I am trying to do [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

Comment: "I think this will be very inefficient" – just go with the easiest solution unless you _know_ it will be too inefficient for you.  You've probably heard that quote about premature optimisation.

Comment: Yes but I need to generate 10^6 numbers and if each one takes 1 second using this method it will take me 11 days to so (this depends on how precise I want to be) I'd appreciate anything that optimizes this.

Comment: Just try it – there is no reason to assume it will take one second.  A very easy way to implement this is to subclass `scipy.stats.rv_continuous` and override the `_pdf()` method with your `p` function.  The class provides a default implementation for the inverse of the CDF in the form of the `ppf()` method.

Comment: I just noticed you want to get samples for the distribution.  In this case you can directly call the `rvs()` method.

Comment: You are doing Monte Carlo experimentation. That being the case, make a reasonably good estimate of the inverse cdf for use by scipy's rvs method. Any numerical error will be swamped by sampling error.